# Unofficial PhD admission

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

I am looking for some clarifications to how graduate committees' proceed. Looking at GradCafe it seems that some mathematics departments sent e-mails admitting students to their PhDs already, even if the final official letter will come in February only. Indeed, the accepted students write *"unofficial email from the Graduate Program Administrator."*

My questions are two: first, what is the graduate program administrator? Moreover, if I haven't received an email from this department in this unofficial email shift, does it mean that I have not been admitted and that I will be (at best) waitlisted? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The "Graduate Program Administrator" is... the administrator of the graduate program. For larger programs it's likely to be an office person who manages graduate admissions and recruitment, grants and funding for the graduate program/students, etc. For smaller programs (or simply programs organized differently) it could be a faculty person. It's a real, credible position, but an unofficial offer is not the same as an official one.

If you haven't received an email updating your status, you don't know your status. Probabilistically, if other people have gotten an email *from that particular institution and program* saying they're unofficially admitted, yes, it is less likely you will be admitted if even just by simple probability (like a shell game where some of the answers have been revealed), but you can't know anything for sure. Every department does it differently. Perhaps they emailed some "definite yesses" early and are debating about the rest or are waiting to learn about the certainty of funding from elsewhere in the administration.

**It's not worth your worrying about things like this that are now out of your control.** Just wait until you hear about your own status. I'd highly recommend against trying to scour the internet for hints as to what will happen. It's just not a good use of your time or mental health.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind and helpful answer!

Comment: +10 for the last paragraph

Answer (score 0):

Just anecdotally I got a "you should probably be admitted" text from my current advisor at the end of January last year, followed by a formal admissions offer later in April. I also had to contact the school to have my admissions form processed, as the staff were working from home due to COVID, so it took a couple moths longer to send out letters.